# Django - Adding custom class to label_tag

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to figure out a way to add a class to my  tag on my form. I want to accomplish this without something like crispyforms and if possible not having to edit the html. Based on my knowledge and googling I have spent a few hours trying to figure this out but I cannot haha. I basically just want to output a class in the label element like so:

```
<label class='text-muted' for="id_street_address">Street Address:</label>
```

My model is as follows:

```
class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    street_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))
    apartment = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    zip_code = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))
    same_billing_address = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
    save_info = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
    payment_option = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['street_address'].label = 'Street Address'
        self.fields['apartment'].label = 'Address 2 (optional)'
        self.fields['zip_code'].label = 'Zip Code'
```

I render my form in the template like this:

```
<form>
              {% csrf_token %}
              {% for field in form %}
              <div class="form-group px-3 my-3">
              {{ field.label_tag }}
              {{ field }}
              {{ field.help_text }}
              {{ field.errors }}
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
            </form>
```

Is it possible to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Use Crispy forms. Just do! (I know that's not an answer, which is why its a comment :-)

Comment: Haha I know it would be easier but I feel like learning how to do it without those packages will help me more in the long run. It helps me have a better fundamental knowledge of django in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that actually renders the form field is the class `BoundField`. This bound field has a method [`label_tag` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.label_tag) which you are using to render the label, this method does accept some optional parameters one of which is `attrs` using which we should be able to add the `class` attribute you want. The problem here though is:

1. We cannot pass parameters to the method in the template.
2. Overriding it would involve overriding the form fields too, which means overriding multiple form fields.

One solution would be to implement a [custom template tag / filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) to call the method for us, which is what I will describe in this answer. First create a directory `templatetags` in some suitable app of yours, add a `__init__.py` file to it, and a file in which we will write our template tag (let us say `form_helpers.py`). Hence your app directory will now look something like:

```
your_app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        form_helpers.py
    views.py
```

Next in `form_helpers.py` add the following code:

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def render_label(bound_field, css_class):
    return bound_field.label_tag(attrs={'class': css_class})
```

Next in your template you can then write:

```
{% load form_helpers %}

<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group px-3 my-3">
            {% render_label field css_class="text-muted" %}
            {{ field }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field.errors }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

---

**Note**: There is a great package for rendering forms manually called [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks), if you use it you could have simply used its `add_required_class` filter.

Comment: Wow! This is extremely insightful and interesting comment. I had an idea earlier in the day that maybe I could accomplish it with templatetags but my skills weren't great enough to figure it out haha. This worked perfectly and it was explained in a way that is easy to comprehend. I really appreciate the help. Definitely would have never thought of this solution on my own